# Java Swing simple center of JPanel in other JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have this incredibly easy task of wanting a nice centered `JPanel` inside another `JPanel`. The parent is set to `900, 550`, and the child should be approximately `200,400` or so.

To do this, I thought giving the parent a `BorderLayout` and then setting the `setPreferredSize(200, 400)` of the child. This child would be in the `CENTER`. Two empty JPanels would be on the `EAST` and `WEST`. Of course this did not work. Giving the two sidepanels a `setPreferredSize()` of course DID work. Problem with this is that narrowing the Frame causes the center pane to go away.

Here's some sample code that should give show the issue:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Temporary {

    public static Temporary myObj = null;
    private JFrame mainFrame;

    public void go(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Swing");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,550));

        JPanel mainCards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        mainCards.add(loginLayer(),  "Login");

        mainFrame.setContentPane(mainCards);
        mainFrame.pack();
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel loginLayer(){
        JPanel masterPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel centerPane = new JPanel();
        centerPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        centerPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Swing is overly");
        label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        centerPane.add(label);
        JButton button = new JButton("complicated");
        button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        centerPane.add(button);
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        centerPane.add(textField);

        JPanel filler = new JPanel();
        JPanel filler2 = new JPanel();

        masterPane.add(filler, BorderLayout.WEST);
        masterPane.add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        masterPane.add(filler2, BorderLayout.EAST);

        return masterPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        myObj = new Temporary();
        myObj.go();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BorderLayout` will, by it's nature, give as much of the available space as it can to the `CENTER` component.  This is how it's designed.

If you want the component to be centered within the parent container, BUT maintain it's preferred size, you should consider using a `GridBagLayout` instead.  Without any additional constraints, this should achieve the result you're after

For example...

```
public JPanel loginLayer(){
    JPanel masterPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout);

    JPanel centerPane = new JPanel();
    centerPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Swing is overly");
    label.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    centerPane.add(label);
    JButton button = new JButton("complicated");
    button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    centerPane.add(button);
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    centerPane.add(textField);

    masterPane.add(centerPane);

    // Add additional borders to providing padding around the center pane
    // as you need

    return masterPane;
}
```

I would also avoid actively setting the preferred size of component in this way, as it's possible that the components you're adding to it will exceed your expectations, instead, make use of things like `EmptyBorder` (for example) to add additional white space arouond the component and it's contents

Comment: Excellent! Also removed the `setPreferredSize` as you mentioned, and it's aligned nicely in the center, vertically and horizontally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Java Swing, you generally want to avoid creating a bunch of statically positioned items with preferred sizes and absolute positions, because things get weird with resizing (as you've noticed).  Instead you want to rely on the fluid `LayoutManager`s.  There is an excellent tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).  Or, if you want to supply a mock-up of some sort to show the actual UI you are trying to create, I could provide some more feedback.

Comment: +1 If for nothing else but the comments about avoiding preferred size

Comment: I do try avoid absolute positioning, but I do use preferred size quite a lot. I will definitely try and avoid this in future projects, thanks!